# Get progress of upload with DavidWebb for Android

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I've found the code to uploade in this answer: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/55472

```
Webb webb = Webb.create();
Response<String> response = webb
        .post("http://www.example.com/service")
        .body(new File("camera/myfile.jpg"))
        .connectTimeout(10 * 1000)
        .asString();

if (response.isSuccess()) {
    String outcome = response.getBody();

    // ...

} else {
    System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());
    System.out.println(response.getResponseMessage());
    System.out.println(response.getErrorBody());
}
```

But how can I track the progress of the upload?

Comment: Use Log.d() rather that System.out.printLn().

Comment: As @ssh stated correctly, there is no native support for Multi-Part. But it would be possible to implement a callback for progress of upload for this simple example (just upload one file). If you want it, create an issue on Github and I'll implement it. Will work for `.body(File)`, but not for `.body(InputStream)`, as the number of bytes must be known in advance.

Comment: Thanks @hgoeble.  I've learned our backend is expecting a multi-part upload. I'll be trying to implement this ontop of your lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see  Multi-Part upload

[image]

**is not available feature** of this library, so you can't get a progress of uploading file.

You need use MultiPart to upload file to server. More [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/)

Comment: Thanks fof the link to the tutorial. It's to much code to post in answer ;)